# I am having trouble in Python - from import does not working

Tags: python

I am trying to import from a specific python file (which I wrote) class that in that file and it seems that python just does not recognize my file.
add image to represent the situation more deeply:
that the file I want to import the Ball class from:

[image]

the main file and the error:

[image]

[mylib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye92F.png)
[the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLyty.png)

Comment: Maybe go read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: That warning is coming from the IDE, do you get an error when you actually run the script?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). [please do not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)
[as they are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: yes they are...

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing the project's structure

Comment: He seems to have two files one called main_Pygame.py which he calls as the script and one called shapes.py that is in the same directory. btw, I did not notice right away, but he has two links in his question next to each other rather than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import from the same directory, put a dot at the front of the module name like:

```
from .shapes import Ball
```

But if you are running main_Pygame.py as the script then this will not work. You should create a subdirectory for shapes.py, say `mylib` and then make an empty file called `__init__.py` there and mve shapes.py to that directory. Then import like:

```
from mylib.shapes import Ball
```

The `__init__.py` file tells python that the `mylib` directory (or whatever else you wish to call the directory) is part of the directory tree it should look for modules under.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/idofr/PycharmProjects/FirstPythonProject/Python_3.8_projects/GAME/more_Pygame.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .shapes import Ball
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Ah so you must be running more_Pygame.py as main script?

Comment: yes, the import seems to work but i got this error

Comment: That strange.... I am quite sure that I did it right but now python does not recognize the mylib dict

Comment: added another pic in the question

Comment: I am seeing pics rather than links in the questions now, but they look like the same way as you had it. Just. as a check list 1) The script you call should be in a directory by itself. 2) This directory should have a subdirectory, lets call it mylib. 3) An empty file named `__init__.py` with two underscore characters before and after the init part should be in our mylib subdirectory. 4) The shapes.py file should be in the subdirectory. 5) The import should then be `from mylib.shapes import Ball`

Comment: yeah i did it, look at the bottom of the question its some link or somthing

Comment: they called mylib and files

Comment: Oh I see now. Looks like you have mylib next to the GAME directory. But mylib should be inside the GAME directory as a subdirectory.

Comment: I fixed wording of question to make it more clear I meant mylib to be a subdirectory.

Comment: yep! now it's all working, thank you very much for your quick answer and patience.